# Error LNK1181 with a pip install "cannot open input file 'mysqlclient.lib'"

Tags: python, mysql, module

I am new to Python and i'm trying to install the mysql modules, but after resolving fiew other problems, i now have this issue that appears when i try to install the module, here are the logs:

```
PS C:\Users\ùposte> pip install mysql
Collecting mysql
  Using cached mysql-0.0.1.tar.gz
Collecting MySQL-python (from mysql)
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python, mysql
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\ùposte\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\POSTE~2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-l2boilyg\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\POSTE~2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-74885xzp-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\users\ùposte\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\ùposte\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(192): warning C4005: 'isnan': macro redefinition
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(275): note: see previous definition of 'isnan'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(203): warning C4005: 'SIZEOF_OFF_T': macro redefinition
    c:\users\—poste\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include\pyconfig.h(324): note: see previous definition of 'SIZEOF_OFF_T'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(301): warning C4005: 'HAVE_STDDEF_H': macro redefinition
    c:\users\—poste\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include\pyconfig.h(602): note: see previous definition of 'HAVE_STDDEF_H'
    _mysql.c(297): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(327): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(623): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(624): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(625): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(626): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(627): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1118): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1161): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1165): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1532): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" /LIBPATH:c:\users\ùposte\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\ùposte\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.16299.0\um\x86" kernel32.lib advapi32.lib wsock32.lib mysqlclient.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__mysql build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.6\_mysql.cp36-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_mysql.cp36-win32.lib
    LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'mysqlclient.lib'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\ùposte\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\POSTE~2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-l2boilyg\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\POSTE~2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-74885xzp-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\POSTE~2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-l2boilyg\MySQL-python\
PS C:\Users\ùposte>
```

Same error for pip install mysql-python and all the stuff that i need..